# How to discover the hostname on which the VirtualBox GUI runs?

Tags: virtualbox

I run `VirtualBox` on multiple CentOS hosts, and on occasion, I have several `VirtualBox` GUIs open on my workstation.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2yMa.png)

I didn't find a way to discover - from a `VirtualBox` GUI, which is the hostname the VirtualBox GUI is running on.
I'm expecting that from somewhere in the VirtualBox GUI (as depicted below), the VirtualBox host's hostname would be available: I just cannot determine where this place in the GUI is.

Do you know where I can find the hostname on which the VirtualBox runs?

### [image: How the VirtualBox GUI is seen on my workstation]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2yMa.png) I ssh to the target VirtualBox machine with ssh -Y, and then 
when I issue the command virtualbox, the VirtualBox GUI shows on my workstation.

Answer (score 1):

Apps generally don't have any such indication as part of their own UI; VirtualBox also doesn't.

Instead, X11 clients are supposed to set the `WM_CLIENT_MACHINE` property on their own windows, indicating what host they come from. (You can see it using `xprop`.) Some X11 clients do not do this, but VirtualBox 6.0.10 (being a standard Qt5 application) certainly does.

Your local window manager will usually detect this property, and will automatically append the hostname to the window title whenever it's different from the local Xserver hostname. (As long as the app is not using "client-side window decorations", but neither Qt nor VirtualBox use them.)

[image: Screenshot of two VirtualBox Manager windows overlapping, one of them suffixed with "(on ember)" to indicate the remote hostname.]

If this isn't happening, first check using `xprop` whether the window property actually exists. If it exists and indicates the remote hostname correctly, your window manager is at fault. (GNOME's Metacity​/​Mutter​/​Shell has supported this since 2006.)

As a last resort, create an empty VM and name it something like "___ Host vmhost01 ___" to put it at the top of each server's list...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @grawity. Unfortunately, `xprop` does not show reference to the remote machine virtualbox GUI's hostname (namely, `xprop | grep 
 <hostname>`, after the crosshairs chose the GUI window, comes back empty).

Comment: Does the problem also affect other apps (such as xterm, gtk3-demo, firefox, and so on)?

Comment: Not that I've noticed. For instance, firefox adds an `(on <hostname>)` to its window's title.